# Send attachment from Android Device to another automatically

Tags: android, push-notification, attachment, email-attachments

I have  Android Studio code that creates a new `Wav` file every 30 seconds, I need to send these `wav` files to another device ( As some sort of notification) as they are made.

I can't use the traditional android studio default/built-in app for this as I need to send the email automatically without user input. I found a way to send the email automatically in background, from the source below, but I cannot get it to send the `wav` file attachment:

http://www.wisdomitsol.com/blog/android/sending-email-in-android-without-using-the-default-built-in-application

Any advice about the best way to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean fileExists = new File(filePath).exists();

In filePath provide your file path which you want to send in attachment.
```